# .htaccess custom URL forwarding rules using pattern matching

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been attempting (without success) to implement the following logic in .htaccess:

www.domain.com/**aa**/ redirects to www**2**.domain.com/**aa**/
www.domain.com/**bb**/ redirects to www**3**.domain.com/**bb**/
 
www.domain.com/**cc**/ redirects to www**4**.domain.com/**cc**/
www.domain.com/**dd**/ redirects to www**4**.domain.com/**dd**/
www.domain.com/**ee**/ redirects to www**4**.domain.com/**ee**/

.htaccess rules also needs to preserve all directories/page names in the URL:

www.domain.com/**aa**/collectionA/productB
redirects to
www**2**.domain.com/**aa**/collectionA/productB

www.domain.com/**bb**/collectionC/productD
redirects to
www**3**.domain.com/**bb**/collectionC/productD

www.domain.com/**cc**/collectionD/productE
redirects to
www**4**.domain.com/**cc**/collectionD/productE


Any solutions would be most welcome! Thank you.

Comment: By "forwards" do you mean redirecting the browser or having the webserver reverse proxy the request on behalf of the browser?

Comment: redirects - edited the original question - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^aa(/.*)?$ http://www2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^bb(/.*)?$ http://www3.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Place this code in your `/cc/.htaccess`, `/dd/.htaccess` and `/ee/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www4.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

**Update:** As per comments you can have this rule in root .htaccessof each domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /aa/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www3\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /ab/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava - I just edited the question with more information to explain the logic required more completely

Comment: Did you test these rules? I believe it would with your revised question also. If for some reason it doesn't report back with URLs for which it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I tested the above rules and they have the following two issues:

1) URLs were not preserved after the first directory: 

www.domain.com/cc/collectionD/productE
redirected to
www4.domain.com/cc/

2) The first two rules for aa and bb did not work. Only the rule for cc|dd|ee worked. I tried the following rule which works for aa or bb, but does not pass on the URL:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/aa/ http://www2.domain.com/aa

So we are still quite far from a working solution!

Comment: Did I suggest using `RedirectMatch` any where? All the rules I suggested preserve the original URI. Make sure you have just these rules and nothing else. Also make sure there is no other .htaccess anywhere in your system.

Comment: I have .htaccess files under cc, dd and ee, which are required for website operation. www4 is parked on the same hosting account as www. www2 and www3 are served via separate hosting accounts. Will I need to separate hosting accounts for www and www4 to get the required .htaccess logic? (separating the hosting would create problems, so I am trying to avoid this)

Comment: ok check updated as last rules will be needed in **each** of the .htaccess files under cc, dd and ee.

Comment: Thanks anubhava - this worked perfectly! Just one question, how/where to set 'roots' to redirect to new locations: www2.domain.com to www2.domain.com/aa, www3.domain.com to  to www3.domain.com/bb, www4.domain.com to www4.domain.com/cc. Currently these are not covered by any rules. Thank you!